# Not mandatory of "a" and "an"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

For a grammatically correct construction, is the use of the article **"a"** unnecessary in the following clause, between *"in" and "coastal"*, and of the **"an"** before *"estuarine"*?

> Oil spill simulations and susceptibility **in coastal** and **estuarine**
>   areas.

Comment: *Areas* is plural. You can't use either *a* or *an* with something plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be just downright wrong to use indefinite articles like *a* and *an* in this sentence because *coastal areas* is one single concept that represents something that's plural (in other words, it's something that's more than one in number). Likewise, *estuarine areas* is another single concept that also represents something that's plural. Indefinite articles are only used in front of things that represent singular ideas. Your sentence is quite obviously not that case. This is how you could read the sentence:

> Oil spill simulations and susceptibility in **coastal areas** and in **estuarine areas**.

If you do insist on using indefinite articles, then the sentence would have to be rewritten like this:

> Oil spill simulations and susceptibility in **a coastal area** and in **an estuarine area**.

Comment: It also sounds a little *headlinese*, like the title of a scholarly article.